# HTML - creating multiple buttons that lead to different html pages not working

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have two buttons below called 'create' and 'back'.

Both buttons should lead to different html pages but for some reason only create works and back doesn't lead to anything even though the code is basically the exact same thing as create except with `<b href">` instead of `<a href>`.

I'm not sure if `b href` is just not a valid thing? I tried looking up examples of creating buttons and they all use `a href` but I can't use 'a' because both buttons have different characteristics in css.

I was wondering how could I fix this issue? I'm having trouble getting multiple buttons to lead to their own different pages, each with their own design/class in css.

Create leads to a page called 'create.html' whereas clicking on Back does nothing. It doesn't even lead to a page with the 'doesn't exist' error, I'm basically just clicking on text. It doesn't even act like a button.

```css
#create {
  height: 45px;
  width: 230px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px #000000;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 0.9em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1000px;
  top: 300px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 27px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#back {
  height: 45px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px #000000;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 0.9em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1600px;
  top: 400px;
}

b {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="create"><a href="home.html">CREATE USER</a></div>

<div id="back"><b href="main.html">Go back to the homepage</b></div>
```

Comment: You are trying to use `b` tag for a link. But it is supposed to be used to draw the reader's attention to the element's contents [b tag doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b). So make it as `a` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `<b>` is not valid link (anchor tag) use `<a>` instead of `<b>` and style like in the snippet.

```css
#create {
  height: 45px;
  width: 230px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px #000000;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 0.9em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1000px;
  top: 300px;
}
#create a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 27px;
  text-align: center;

  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#back {
  height: 45px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px #000000;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 0.9em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1600px;
  top: 400px;
}
#back a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;

  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="create"><a href="home.html">CREATE USER</a></div>

<div id="back"><a href="main.html">Go back to the homepage</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The <a> tag defines a hyperlink, which is used to link from one page to another.
If you want different css characteristics you could use different classes to style.

See: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp